# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" Error when attempting to download S3 file with iOS SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to download a file from my S3 server with the new AWS Mobile SDK v2.0.5, and everything seems to be working fine, but when the download is executed, it throws this error: "-[AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc12f520" Here is the code I have:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
                                                          credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1vaccountId:@"ID" unauthRoleArn:@"ID" authRoleArn:@"ID"];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    [[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
        NSString* cognitoId = credentialsProvider.identityId;
        return nil;
    }];

    AWSS3 *s3 = [[AWSS3 new] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [[AWSS3TransferManager alloc] initWithS3:s3];
    AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *getFileRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
    getFileRequest.bucket = @"MY_BUCKET";
    getFileRequest.key = @"MY_KEY";
    [[transferManager download:getFileRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
        if (task.error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
        }
        else {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.dat"];
            NSData *data = task.result;
            NSString *download = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *error;
            [download writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

What would cause this to happen? If you need any other info about anything feel free to ask.

Comment: For one thing, you should change `[[AWSS3 new] initWithConfiguration:configuration];` to `[[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];`.

Comment: Alright that didn't fix the issue but thanks for that tip! I'm still relatively new to AWS...

Comment: There seems to be a lot of object hierarchy for AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest, I haven't looked all the way up but somewhere along the lines it needs to implement the NSCoding protocol.  Is there a stack trace from the crash you could use to see why encodeWithCoder: is being called?

Comment: '5   Foundation                          0x0264d8f0 _encodeObject + 1291' This is the only thing in the stack I could find that deals with encoding after this is does a "forwarding-prep", then "forwarding" and then the error occurs

Comment: Just spotted this '6 Foundation 0x0264d3dd -[NSKeyedArchiver encodeObject:forKey:] + 197' Not sure if its important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are using the frameworks and forgot to add `-ObjC` to **Other Linker Flags**. You can read [Set Up the SDK for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) for more details.

Comment: I saw where it said to do that, but under my Other Linker Flags, I don't get how I'm supposed to add Objc

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out and problem solved! Thanks!